# Angular FormGroup invalid not correct during Cypress test

Tags: angular, electron, cypress

I have a button that is disabled while the `formGroup` is invalid. The button becomes valid under the following condition:

```
 const field = this.formBuilder.group({
      fieldType: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      fieldName: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(2)
      ]),
      fieldValue: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(1)
      ]),
      fieldUnit: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(2)
      ])
    });
```

This works fine interacting manually and when running my Cypress test from the console

```
 cy.contains("Save changes").click();
```

but when running from the Cypress electron browser the button is still disabled after valid entry has been made. I even tried waiting a second after input to no effect.

This is the code that checks for validation ts and html respectively.

```
 isInvalid(): boolean {
    const { invalid } = this.metadataForm; // FormGroup
    return invalid;
  }

<button
  mat-flat-button
  type="submit"
  color="primary"
  [disabled]="isInvalid()"
  (click)="doSave()"
>
  <mat-icon> save </mat-icon>
  Save changes
</button>
```

In the electron browser one can clearly see that the button is disabled when it should be enabled. So why is the electron browser not performing correctly?

**EDIT:**

@Prince kindly created a basic [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-47uvne). I ran the same tests against this and it worked as it should. with the button becoming enabled and then being clicked.

below is the test.

```
describe("visit", () => {
    it("should go to site", () => {
      cy.visit('https://angular-validation-kr7qun.stackblitz.io');
      cy.get('form.ng-untouched > :nth-child(1) > .ng-untouched').type("some name{enter}");
      cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .ng-untouched').type("some name{enter}");
      cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .ng-untouched').type("some name{enter}");
      cy.get(':nth-child(4) > .ng-untouched').type("some name{enter}");
      cy.get('button').click()
    });
  });
```

[image]

error in electron browser:

> vendor.js:68863 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'items ->
>   0 -> fieldType'
>       at _throwError (vendor.js:106904)
>       at setUpControl (vendor.js:106812)
>       at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl
>   (vendor.js:110038)
>       at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName._setUpControl
>   (vendor.js:110639)
>       at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges
>   (vendor.js:110560)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (vendor.js:85954)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (vendor.js:94356)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (vendor.js:94318)
>       at prodCheckAndUpdateNode (vendor.js:94859)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///ScientificMetadataModule/MetadataEditComponent.ngfactory.js:478)

This this is actually an issue with the dynamic form implementation

Comment: Could you put that directly `[disabled]="metadataForm?.invalid"`

Comment: @AhmedKesha sadly, didnt help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i need to specify the error in your code, then you are referring to wrong method name of component class.

In component class you are using method with name - `isInvalid()`. But  in template you are using `isValid()`.

I would suggest you the ideal way would be just refer FormGroup in temlate directly to check its validity. With this you can remove redundant code, its just for simplicity. Use it like below:

```
<button
  mat-flat-button
  type="submit"
  color="primary"
  [disabled]="metadataForm.invalid"
  (click)="doSave()"
>
  <mat-icon> save </mat-icon>
  Save changes
</button>
```

Please create a stackblitz instance here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-47uvne

I don't know why its not working at your end, can you please create a stackblitz instance for your issue.

Comment: ok not the issue, just a mistake in the question. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz instance for your issue ?

Comment: Updated my answer, please check the stackblitz instance.

Comment: did you run the cypress test against it?

Comment: i think youre missing the point that its the cypress test that is failing.

Comment: True, can you please stacjblitz instance or anything so that i can see your issue?

Comment: thanks for you help. Your stackblitz was useful. I found the issue. the first validation is for a selection box but isnt being input as such by cypress as im using type instead of click()

Comment: Glad, that i am helpful in some way.